# Map subsets of data from a multidimensional array to create an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, associative-array

I have some variables returned from `get_defined_vars()` and I need to map two subsets of data together to form a flat associative array.

Input:

```
[
    'lead' => [
        2 => 'fstory',
        4 => 'him',
        5 => 'trtr',
        1 => '508b38ee02f502.23680245.png',
    ],
    'form' => [
        'id' => 3,
    ],
    'fields' => [
        [
            'adminLabel' => 'formname',
            'id' => 2,
        ],
        [
            'adminLabel' => 'hisher',
            'id' => 4,
        ],
        [
            'adminLabel' => 'fname',
            'id' => 5,
        ],
        [
            'adminLabel' => 'sign',
            'id' => 1,
        ]
    ]
]
```

I need to the `[fields][adminLabel]` elements to become keys and the `[lead][#]` elements to be the values.

Desired result:

```
[
    'formname' => 'fstory'
    'fname' => 'trtr'
    'hisher' => 'his'
    'sign' => '508b38ee02f502.23680245.png',
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It is untested.

```
$result_values  = $array['lead'];
$results        = array();
foreach ($array['form']['fields'] as $value) {
  if (is_array($value)) {
    $results[$value['adminLabel']] = $result_values[$value['id']];
  }  
}
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the `fields` subset and use the `id` values to access the corresponding `lead` values.

Classic foreach(): ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JaotY))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array['fields'] as $row) {
    extract($row);
    $result[$adminLabel] = $array['lead'][$id];
}
var_export($result);
```

---

array_reduce(): ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AZgO9))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $array['fields'],
        fn($result, $row) =>
            $result + [$row['adminLabel'] => $array['lead'][$row['id']]],
        []
    )
);
```